# FactoryBot objects missing certain properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, factory-bot

I'm trying to use [FactoryBot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot) to create some test data. One of my factories is giving me trouble: it works fine when I instantiate with default values, but when I specify values for certain attributes, **a different attribute** comes out as `nil`.

The model class indicates that one of the values is an enum, both have presence validators, and one value has has a unique key scoped to the other value. I have tried various options like using `add_attribute` and `sequence` in my factory definitions.

What am I missing? Is FactoryBot trying to treat this as an implicit association?

````rb
# app/models/course.rb
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  validates :source, :source_id, presence: true
  validates :source_id, uniqueness: {scope: :source, message: "duplicate id for specified source"}
  enum source: {
    test: 0,
    sis: 1,
    lms: 2,
    cs: 3
  }
end

# db/schema.rb
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2022_03_14_195055) do
  create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "source"
    t.string "source_id"
  end
end

# test/factories.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :course do
    source_id { "1234" }
    source { "test" }
  end
end

# test code
puts build(:course)
puts build(:course, source: "test").inspect
puts build(:course, source_id: "9999").inspect
puts build(:course, source: "test", source_id: "9999")

# Output
#<Course id: nil, source: "test", source_id: "1000" ... >
#<Course id: nil, source: "test", source_id: nil ... >
#<Course id: nil, source: nil, source_id: "9999" ... >
#<Course id: nil, source: nil, source_id: nil ... >```
````

Answer (score 2):

I just realized this is a [known issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/1142) in FactoryBot. The solution seems to be something like:

```rb
factory :person do
  name { "Daniel" }

  transient do
    thing_id { 0 }
    thing { "thing" }
  end

  initialize_with do
    new(attributes.merge(thing_id: thing_id, thing: thing))
  end
end
```